# how to access google analytics api with C#.NET?

Tags: api, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I had registered my website at Google-Analytics, now I wanted to get all the visit resords with C#.NET and show them on my webpage, I had even downloaded SDK from google but found no samples within it. Can anyone who have experienced for it help me? Thanks!